# How to Create Collection from a existing Collection based on unique Name Eg : "Traits":/Name/

Tags: mongodb

Iam new to Mongo. I want to Create a new collection from an existing collection using variable Name

Eg : "Traits":/data/

I have 100 documents in a collection.In that 100 documents 40 documents have "data" in Name variable.So I want to create 40 documents as separate collection from existing collection.Can anyone help how to create new collection.Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you done any research? Please add to your post what you have tried so far, and what the results were.

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggrgation framework with $match and $out stage:

```
db.oldDB.aggregate([
{$match:{name:/data/}},
{$out:"newColl"}
])
```

This way you will have newColl with only documents where name field contains data.

Comment: Hi Matth,
Using above query I am able to create new collection.But collection shows empty Documents
db.getCollection('newColl').find({}) results  0 documents.

Comment: did you use it as written?See that your field is 'Name', not 'name'. But provide samples, I will adjust my answer.